# read a path from file in a correct syntax with streamreader

Tags: c#, streamreader

I'm completely a junior here. I have tried something like

- save a path and file string in a file like:

  ```
  c:\aaa\bbb\text.txt
  ```
- then I need to read again as path but I get `c:\aaa\bbb\text.txt`   from streamreader, but I need `c:\\\aaa\\\bbb\\\text.txt`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you save `c:\aaa\bbb\text.txt` into a file - why do you expect to get back `c:\\\aaa\\\bbb\\\text.txt` when you read it? How should the `StreamReader` magically know that you want all the backslashes three times each??!?!?!??? You need to get back what you stored - and **if** you need to modify it - it's up to **YOU** to do so after you read it ....

Comment: `I need c:\\\aaa\\\bbb\\\text.txt` Why do you assume you need that? Escaping is only needed when writing string literals *in the code itself* - except when you use verbatim literals, eg `@"c:\aaa\bbb\text.txt"`. You can write `File.ReadAllText(@"c:\aaa\bbb\text.txt")` to read that file's content. What your code reads is a perfectly valid file path. If you write `File.ReadAllText(thatPath);` you won't get any errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be confusing string *literals* with a string.

Say I write `var myString = "\\"` or `var myString = @"\"`, this will show in the debugger as `\\`, because the debugger will format it as a literal. But if print it to the console, a file, or press the magnifying glass next to the string in the debugger, it will be shown as `\`, because that is the actual string value. See also [verbatim string literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim)

So, if you do `myStreamWriter.Write("c:\\aaa\\bbb\\text.txt");`, you will be actually saving the string `c:\aaa\bbb\text.txt`, and that is also the string that will be read back.

However I fail to understand why you would want *three* slashes, I can only assume the OP thinks the escaping is done multiple times.